# trying to set the body background image through selector option

Tags: html

I am trying to change my background image when each selected item is chosen through the selector, i am wondering if anyone can help in what i am doing wrong. It is currently setting the selector options to the background when each one is selected and not the body.

```
<body id="mainBody" background="resources/imgs/background2.jpg" >
<select onchange="changeBackGround();" id="selectBackGround">
<option value="Original">Original</option>
<option value="GreyScale">GreyScale</option>
<option value="Colorful">Colorful</option>
</select>



 var changeBackGround = function(){
var mainBody = document.getElementById("selectBackGround");
if(document.getElementById("selectBackGround").value === "Original"){
      mainBody.style.backgroundImage = "url('resources/imgs/background2.jpg')";
}else if(document.getElementById("selectBackGround").value === "GreyScale"){
      mainBody.style.backgroundImage = "url('resources/imgs/greyscale.jpg')";
  }else{
      mainBody.style.backgroundImage = "url('resources/imgs/colored.jpg')";
  }
  mainBody.style.backgroundImage = document.getElementById("selectBackGround").value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var mainBody = document.getElementById("selectBackGround");
```

to

```
var mainBody = document.getElementById("mainBody");
```

You are applying background to mainBody not selectBackground.

```js
 var changeBackGround = function(){
var mainBody = document.getElementById("mainBody");
if(document.getElementById("selectBackGround").value === "Original"){
      mainBody.style.backgroundImage = "url('resources/imgs/background2.jpg')";
}else if(document.getElementById("selectBackGround").value === "GreyScale"){
      mainBody.style.backgroundImage = "url('resources/imgs/greyscale.jpg')";
  }else{
      mainBody.style.backgroundImage = "url('resources/imgs/colored.jpg')";
  }
  mainBody.style.backgroundImage = document.getElementById("selectBackGround").value;
};
```

```html
<body id="mainBody" background="resources/imgs/background2.jpg" >
<select onchange="changeBackGround();" id="selectBackGround">
<option value="Original">Original</option>
<option value="GreyScale">GreyScale</option>
<option value="Colorful">Colorful</option>
</select>
```